# Searching for multiple files in a directory and provide feedback

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a `.bat` file that will find multiple files in a single directory, and provide feedback if they exist or not.

How to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

In it's simplest form:
`dir Pattern1,Pattern2,Pattern3 >nul 2>&1 && echo found`
`dir` will search for files or directories matching patterns specified (you may use wildchars). If you want only files, `use dir /A-D`
`>nul 2>&1` supresses output from it
`&&` means execute only if previous command was successful (ie dir found a file/dir with that pattern). You may also use `||` meaning opposite (if previous failed).

If you need to check if all patterns exist simply chain instead:
`(dir Pattern1 && dir Pattern2 && dir Pattern3) >nul 2>&1 && echo found`

If you want your batch more readable (!) use `if errolevel` / `if not errorlevel` instead.
Errorlevel is set by dir to 1 if it does not find anything, to 0 if it finds a match.

Of course you may use any other command(s) instead of `echo`

Comment: +1, but you probably should use `DIR /A-D` to make sure you match a file and not a folder. Also a Not found message would be nice: `&&echo Found||echo Not Found`

Comment: @dbenham I wanted it to be more general; reworded to clearly indicate it may match directories also

Comment: That is fine, except the question explicitly asks for files.

Answer (score 3):

wmz has a nice solution if you want to report if any or if all of the files exist. However, you may need to report on the presence or absence of each file in the list.

`IF EXIST "filename"` can be used to test if a file or folder exists. If you want to be sure it is a file and not a folder, then you also need `IF NOT EXIST "filename\"`.

The other option is to use the `DIR /A-D` command and test for success or failure.

A FOR loop makes the code more pleasing and easier to maintain. Don't forget that file names with spaces or special characters like `&` or `|` must be quoted.

Here is a solution using DIR /A-D;

```
@echo off
for %%F in (file1 file2 "file with space") do (
  1>nul 2>nul dir %%F&&echo %%F Found||echo %%F Not Found
)
```

Here is a solution using IF EXIST. Notice how it is OK to put each file on a separate line, That can be easier to read, especially if the list is long.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for %%F in (
  file1
  file2
  "file with space"
) do (
  set "found="
  if exist %%F if not exist %%F\ set found=1
  if defined found (echo %%F Found) else echo %%F Not Found
)
```

Comment: Thanks!The IF Exist filename (echo) ELSE (echo) method works perfectly! Assuming I need to check and match those files in more than 10 hosts with a certain domain.  for example, it will prompt me the host, user id and password to connect to. After inserting them, it will do a search and prompt me the results. Is batch capable of doing so?